# Bluetooth LE L2CAP CID vs. PSM

Tags: c, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, l2cap

I've been teaching myself how to write programs in C for BLE devices using the BlueZ API.  However, I seem to be stumped on one particular aspect of the sockaddr_l2 struct.  The definition I am using is the following:

```
struct sockaddr_l2 {
    sa_family_t l2_family;
    unsigned short  l2_psm;
    bdaddr_t    l2_bdaddr;
    unsigned short  l2_cid;
    uint8_t     l2_bdaddr_type;
};
```

Now for the part I don't understand: what is the difference between l2_psm and l2_cid?  This is what I've gathered so far:

PSM stands for "Protocol Service Multiplexers", and are the L2CAP connection's "port".  Source: Bluetooth for Programmers, by Albert Huang

CID stands for "Channel Identifier", and are local names representing a logical channel end-point on the device.  Source: http://ecee.colorado.edu/~ecen4242/marko/Bluetooth/Bluetooth/SPECIFICATION/L2CAP.html

Now I'm sure the answer is in those definitions, but I just can't seem to wrap my head around the definition of CID.  Can anyone explain to me the differences between PSM and CID in a more comprehensive manner?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the following in Syngress' **Bluetooth Application Developer Guide** from 2002

> *Q: What is the difference between an L2CAP PSM value and an L2CAP CID?*
>
> A: Protocol Service Multiplexor (PSM) values identify the protocol
>   used to communicate over an L2CAP channel. In effect, this defines the
>   higher layer that uses the channel. Multiple instances of the same
>   higher layer may use different L2CAP channels, but they will all be
>   identified by the same PSM value. Each separate channel is uniquely
>   identified by its Channel ID (CID). A higher layer may request an
>   L2CAP connection to a remote RFCOMM entity by specifying a PSM value
>   of 0x0003. The local and remote L2CAP layers then assign CIDs to this
>   link. The CIDs are used to actually identify traffic sent between
>   RFCOMM layers.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the Bluetooth Core Specification v4.2 [Vol 3, Part A, Section 4.2] it states:

> - Protocol/Service Multiplexer - PSM (2 octets (minimum))
>     The PSM field is at least two octets in length. The structure of the PSM field
>     is based on the ISO 3309 extension mechanism for address fields. All PSM
>     values shall be ODD, that is, the least significant bit of the least significant
>     octet must be 1. Also, all PSM values shall have the least significant bit of
>     the most significant octet equal to 0. This allows the PSM field to be
>     extended beyond 16 bits. PSM values are separated into two ranges. Valid
>     values in the first range are assigned by the Bluetooth SIG and indicate
>     protocols. The second range of values are dynamically allocated and used
>     in conjunction with the Service Discovery Protocol (SDP). The dynamically
>     assigned values may be used to support multiple implementations of a
>     particular protocol.

It also provides an outline of an l2cap connection request packet
[image: l2cap Connection Request Packet]

Basically think of the CID as the port, or general communication endpoint. Connections are received on a specific CID and you can request connections on a specific CID. There are even Bluetooth SIG reserved CIDs which you can see in [Vol 3, Part A, Section 2.1]

The PSM on the other hand can be thought of as an identifier for a specific service or device that is trying to connect to you (or for your own device if you are doing the connecting). For example a device requesting a connection to you may specify in documentation to look for a PSM of 0x80.

Answer (score 2):

I am no expert in Bluetooth communication, but I am currently working on an L2CAP LE based communication between a mobile app and a linux based server.

During this development work, I came across something called Connection-oriented Channels and Connectionless Data Channel in the bluetooth SIG specification - Core 4.2. Particluarly in this link: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/bluetooth-core-specification

As far as what I have understood from reading it partly is that the connection-oriented channels are, as the name suggests, connection oriented. That is, each service is associated with a channel.

In case of a connectionless channel, the psm acts as a multiplexer and facilitates multiple services to use the connectionless channel: 0x0002. Thus, psm(protocol/Service multiplexer) basically is similar to a port number in this channel.

These are just my understanding and observations. I am new to this and maybe wrong. I made an effort to write this since I see no real documentation or forum where people have cared to explain their understanding of this concept. The more the merrier.